# Avr isp connection with loaded pins

Tags: avr

Sorry for asking a non-programming question here.
I am making my first circuit with an avrTiny . All my GPIO pins are loaded (resistor + led) . How do i connect my isp header with the load still on the pins

Comment: For your information, there is a SO site [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect each ISP header pin between corresponding AVR pin and it's load. If the load is within spec, all should be fine.

```
 ISP PIN
    ^
    |
 г--*---->AVR PIN
 |
 R
 |
LED
 |
GND
```

Comment: Can you please tell me more about load being within spec ?

Comment: @vpillai, there is a section in datasheet called "Electrical Characteristics". For example ATtiny2313 has 40mA maximum DC current per I/O pin; 200mA max DC at VCC and GND pins. That means each of your  LEDs should draw less than 40mA and all your LEDs in total should draw less than 200mA.

Answer (score 1):

I connect the ISP pins right to the microcontroller pins, then any shared devices on the same bus/pins go through 1k ohm series resistors.  That way if one of the connected devices is driving the net at a different level than the ISP, there's a load to prevent a direct short.

Here is an AVR Freaks form post about this in more detail:
http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=58470